# How to update a glm model that contains NA's after fitting? error Number of observation not equal

Tags: r, glm

I have a dataset that contains some missing values (on independent variables).  I’m fitting a glm model :

`f.model=glm(data = data, formula = y~x1 +x2, "binomial", na.action =na.omit )`

After this model I want the ‘null’ model , so I used `update`:

`n.model=update(f.model, . ~ 1)`

This seems to work, but the number of observations in both models differ (f.model n=234; n.model n=235). So when I try to estimate a likelihood ratio I get an error: `Number of observation not equal!!`.

**Q: How to update the model so that it accounts for the missing values?**

Comment: @ilir, thanks, I have tried that, results in the same error

Comment: OK, then I suggest filtering the data beforehand with `complete.cases()`. Ideally you should be able to tell it to pad the problematic observations with `NA`, but if not, then just exclude them before feeding the data into the model.

Comment: @ilir, Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I thought that `na.action` in glm was made for this kind of problems. Filtering before feeding feels like a detour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is a bit strange that `na.action =na.omit` dit not solve the NA problem. I decided to filter out the data.

```
library(epicalc) # for lrtest

vars=c(“y”, “x1”, “x2”) #variables in the model
n.data=data[,vars] #filter data

f.model=glm(data = data, formula = y~x1 +x2, binomial)

n.model=update(f.model, . ~ 1)

LR= lrtest(n.model,f.model)
```

If someone has a better solution or an argument way `na.action` in combination with `update` results in unequal observations, your answer or solution is more than welcome!